# Cannot access a disposed object. .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I get this error on this line:

```
var removeRole = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(applicationUser, roles);
```

Here is the code:

```
public async Task SaveClient(UserViewModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        var applicationUser = await DbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id && !x.Deleted);
        if (applicationUser == null) throw new Exception("User not found. ");

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(applicationUser);

        if (!(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(applicationUser, viewModel.Role)))
        {
            var removeRole = await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(applicationUser, roles);
            var addRole = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, viewModel.Role);

            if (viewModel.Role.Equals("Agente") && applicationUser.AgentId == null)
                viewModel.AgentId = "A" + new Random().Next(999) + new Random().Next(999);
        }

        Mapper.Map(viewModel, applicationUser);

        await Edit(applicationUser);

        // return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message + " User not found. ");
    }
}
```

I have tried "using" on the "var applicationUser" line but still no luck.

Any help?

This is my Startup Class Services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
         services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config => {
                    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
         }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IInvestmentRepository, InvestmentRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IPortfolioRepository, PortfolioRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddTransient<IPaypalRepository, PaypalRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IStripeRepository, StripeRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IComissionRepository, ComissionRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IWithdrawRepository, WithdrawRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IDepositRepository, DepositRepository>();
            services.AddAutoMapper();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

Comment: Are u using Entity framework and a  `DbContext`? `DbSet` is usually something you do not use alone. This is always coupled to a `DbContext`. Or is this method part of a class that inherits `DbContext`?

Comment: I am using a GenericRepository `public class UserRepository : GenericRepository<ApplicationUser>, IUserRepository`  there I have this `public DbSet<T> DbSet;` and `DbSet = Context.Set<T>();`

Comment: ok this means that the db context was allready disposed. In .net core your DI does a lot out of the box. You want to make sure the context is not disposed from the DI or something like that

Comment: Please post your startup class and any service related to this action if you want us to be able to help. I am pretty sure your service is incorrectly disposing of the `DbContext`

Comment: If I changed the `var applicationUser = await DbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id && !x.Deleted);` to `var applicationUser = DbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id && !x.Deleted).Result;` I get : `ex.Message = "The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached....`

Comment: Sorry if the comment is confusing

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it by changing:

```
var applicationUser = await DbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id && !x.Deleted);
 if (applicationUser == null) throw new Exception("User not found. ");
```

To this:

```
var applicationUser = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(viewModel.Id).Result;
if (applicationUser == null || applicationUser.Deleted) throw new Exception("User not found. ");
```

Also switched from using **async/await** to **Result**.

Here is the whole code:

```
public Task SaveClient(UserViewModel viewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            var applicationUser = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(viewModel.Id).Result;
            if (applicationUser == null || applicationUser.Deleted) throw new Exception("User not found. ");

            var role = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(applicationUser).Result.FirstOrDefault();

            if (role != viewModel.Role)
            {
                var removeRole = _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(applicationUser, role).Result;
                var addRole = _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, viewModel.Role).Result;

                if (viewModel.Role.Equals("Agente") && applicationUser.AgentId == null)
                    viewModel.AgentId = "A" + new Random().Next(999) + new Random().Next(999);

            }

            Mapper.Map(viewModel, applicationUser);

            Edit(applicationUser);

            return Task.CompletedTask;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message + " User not found. ");
        }
    }
```

I hope this can help someone out there that has not found the answer on another post.

Comment: I would not switch from async await to .Result, as it makes the api synchronous so you will not be able to have parallel calls to it.

Comment: I had to change the `var applicationUser` to a `Result` because I was getting errors about task not completed. I will change the method back to **async/await** and leave the `var applicationUser` as a `Result` and report back. Thanks